# why is n divisible by 1+3i in the ring of Gauss integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

the title says it all. My assumption is, that as I know there is an unique isomorphism between integers and a ring $R$. We have $\phi(n) = n1_{\overline{R}} = (1 + 3i)R$. So, this may mean that $n$ is divisible by $(1 + 3i)$. Here $R$ is the ring of Gauss integers and $I$ is the principal ideal generated by $(1 + 3i)$. But I can't prove it strictly. Maybe I even did this wrong? Or what is your idea about this? How can it be proved?

[image]

Comment: This is the definition of a principle ideal: $(a)=\{\,ra\mid r\in R\,\}$

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. It's not the case that _all_ integers $n$ are divisible by $1+3i$, but all integers in the kernel - that is, all integers $n$ with $10\mid n$ - are (also) divisible by $1+3i$.

Comment: Yes, I know that we have multiples of $(1 + 3i)$ in $I$, but how that implies that I also should have $n$ divisible by it? where $n$ is an element of kernel.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes I mean that, why the kernel elements are divisible by $(1 + 3i)$?

Comment: or to be more precise why $n$ should be in the ideal of $I$?

Comment: By the way, the title rarely says it all, and in this case it does not, since we have no idea what $n$ is from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\ w=1\!+\!3i.\ $  The  map $\, \varphi\color{#0a0}{ \ {\rm is\ surjective\  (onto)}}\,$ since $\, \   {\rm mod}\ w\!:\ \,w\bar w=10\equiv 0,\,\ {-}3i\equiv 1\,\overset{\times\,3}\Rightarrow\,i\equiv 3\,\Rightarrow\, a+bi\equiv a+3b\in\Bbb Z$

$\color{#c00}{I = \ker\varphi = 10\,\Bbb Z}\ $ follows by rationalizing a denominator

$\ \ n\in I\iff 1\!+\!3i\mid n\ \, {\rm in}\, \ \Bbb Z[i]\iff \dfrac{n}{1\!+\!3i}\in \Bbb Z[i]\iff \dfrac{n(1\!-\!3i)}{10}\in\Bbb Z[i]\iff \color{#c00}{10\mid n}\qquad$

So applying the First Isomorphism Theorem, $\, \color{#0a0}{R = {\rm Im}\ h} \,\cong\, \Bbb Z/\color{#c00}{\ker h} \,=\, \Bbb Z/\color{#c00}{10\,\Bbb Z}$

Comment: thanks, but why $n$ being in kernel of $\phi$ implies that it is divisible by $(1 + 3i)$ in $Z[i]$? is it a direct result of a ring homomorphism?

Comment: and can it be derived from properties of ring homomorphism? like I did in my question?

Comment: @shotakobakhidze $\ n\in {\rm ker}\phi\iff n = 0\,$ in $R/I\iff n\in I = (3\!+\!i)R,\,$ where $\,R = \Bbb Z[i].\ $ Which part is not clear?

Comment: we have $\phi(n) = 0$ but does it imply that $n = 0$?

Comment: @shota  More precisely: $\varphi$ maps $\,n\,$ to $\,n+I\,$ in $\,R/I,\,$ and $\,n+I = 0+I\iff n-0\in I\ $

Comment: yes, now everything is clear!

Comment: @shota Great. The common abuse of notation can sometimes be puzzling at first glance.